# Listing files according to complex pattern

Tags: r

I've got a list of files that I want to import into R. They look like this:

```
 > dput(asia)
   "chin074.csv", "indi001.csv", "indi001e.csv", "indi001l.csv", 
   "indi001n.csv", "indi001x.csv", "indi002.csv", "indi002e.csv", ...
```

I want to import only those files that do not have a letter after the main name. So, I want to import `chin074.csv` and `indi001.csv` but not  `indi001e.csv` or `indi001l.csv`, which have letters `e` and `l` after the main title.

I know I can use some variation of `grep` to do this, but I can't figure out how. So something like this:

```
asia<-grep(list.files(path="./asia/"), pattern='?', inv=T, value=T) 
asia_new<- lapply(asia, read.csv)
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the pattern :

```
asia <- grep('[a-z]+\\d+\\.csv', asia, value = TRUE)
#[1] "chin074.csv" "indi001.csv" "indi002.csv"
```

We select the files which has one or more lower case letters (`a-z`), followed by one or more numbers, followed by `.csv`.

**data**

```
asia <- c("chin074.csv", "indi001.csv", "indi001e.csv", "indi001l.csv", 
          "indi001n.csv", "indi001x.csv", "indi002.csv", "indi002e.csv")
```

Comment: That works great, thank you. Could you explain how that works? What do the \\ signify? Thank you so much

Comment: First `"\\"` which is `\\d+` is used to select one or more numbers, the second one `\\.` is escaping `"."`. Since `"."` has special meaning in regex if we want to match a literal `"."` we need to escape it which we do here using `"\\"`.

Answer (score 1):

We can also do

```
grep("[a-z]+[0-9]+\\.csv", asia, value = TRUE)
#[1] "chin074.csv" "indi001.csv" "indi002.csv"
```

#### data

```
asia <- c("chin074.csv", "indi001.csv", "indi001e.csv", "indi001l.csv", 
      "indi001n.csv", "indi001x.csv", "indi002.csv", "indi002e.csv")
```